# Updating many-to-many relations in JayData

Tags: many-to-many, odata, entity-relationship, jaydata

My OData model contains a pair of entities with many-to-many relationship (Parents-Children). I am trying to add a child entity to a parent's Children navigation property, but calling saveChanges() afterwards has no effect at all. The code looks something like:

```
// both 'parent' and 'child' are attached to the context
// both have their navigation properties empty
parent.Children.push(child);
context.saveChanges();
```

I have also tried:

```
parent.Children = parent.Children.concat([child]);
parent.Children = [child];
```

But to no avail, it still doesn't work - the saveChanges() call doesn't make any requests to the service, as if there is nothing to update.

I'd really appreciate an example of how to work with many-to-many relations using JayData, and some help dealing with the issue described above.
Thanks

Comment: did you get any further with this?

Comment: @Jmorvan Nope.. Ended up using a regular web api action for updating entities.